# Access one controller inside another in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 master detail page application. So in master page controller I need to access an element which is defined in detail view. How can I do it?

```
jQuery.sap.require("util.Formatter");
jQuery.sap.require("util.Networkaccess");

sap.ui.controller("view.Sales.SalesOrder.SoMaster", {
    myFunc: function() {
        var iconTabBar = this.byId('itabBar'); 
        iconTabBar.setSelectedItem(iconTabBar.getItems()[1]);
    }
})
```

The above code will through error because the `itabBar` element is not there in master view, it's defined in detail view file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am not sure i exactly know what you are trying to do, controls have unique id's prefixed by the view, you could try

```
var iconTabBar = sap.ui.getCore().byId("vwDetails--itabBar")
```

Comment: I find it awkward to add the Details-- prefix in the Master, because in the view itself, byId resolves the prefix automatically. From my point of view, an id should appear only once in the whole application.

Comment: accessing controllers directly is coupling, you should either use events, helper or if your using a component or an appcontroller you can register the controllers there and access them via those singletons, then use oController.getView().byId()